# Number of equivalence relations in a set of 5 elements

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations, set-partition

Let $X$ be a set s.t $|X|=5$ , How many equivalence relations are there from X to itself?

I tried to do it "manually" and I tried to create all possible relationships,

Considering $X$ has Cardinality of 5 we can write that $X=${$a_i|i\in ${$1,..,5$} }

And I tried to list all the possible equivalence relationships, but I find it inelegant, and considering the fact that I previously proven that there's a bijection between the set of all partitions and the set of all equivalence relationships, it would be enough to enumerate all the possible partitions, but I have no idea how to construct all the possible partitions, I have defined the partition as cover of non-void disjunctive sets, and based from this definition I don't know how to proceed

Comment: Just list the partitions

Comment: I already said that in my question, the problem is I don't know how to count them

Comment: You mean you don't know how to count one-two-three-four-... after you make the complete list?

Comment: Since you are dealing with such a small number, you can count by hand the number of partitions. This will probably take less than $5$ minutes.

Comment: if you don't want to count them yourself, you can also just look at wikipedia. p(5) = 7. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)

Comment: @user10354138 I don't know how to list the partions, I don't know where to even start

Comment: @ziggurism OK the number of partitions is 7. but that does not finish the question. For example the partition $3+2$ goes with $\binom{5}{2}=10$ distinct partitions of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}.$

Comment: If $5$ is really too big for you to work with,  start smaller.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what is the partition function for which a wikipedia link is provided in a comment above, but it doesn't seem fit for this question. Here, the OP is asking about partition of sets, and the number of partitions on a $n$-element set is called the Bell number $B_n$, according to [Counting partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Counting_partitions). Thus, for a $5$-element set, we get $B_5=52$.

Comment: Notice that above the linked paragraph, on the right, there is a diagram representing precisely the $52$ partitions on a $5$-element set.

Comment: @amrsa thank you for the correction, that was sloppy of me. Bell number instead of partition number. At least we can say that the partition number gives the correct number of groupings in the Bell number count, but yeah not a helpful direction.

Comment: @ziggurism so do i Need to erite down 52 different partitions? There's not a simplier way?

Comment: @MASSIMILIANOMESSINA If you just want to see the answer, it's in that link that amrsa provided. Here it is again: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#/media/File:Set_partitions_5;_circles.svg. Some methods for computing the count without writing down every partition are also found at that article, such as using the Bell triangle, the recursive formula, or the generating function. I leave it to you to decide whether any of those options counts as "simplier"